# Json Webrequest To C# Object

Tags: c#, json, webrequest

im currently developing an app which has an webrequest: I got the following class (got it from json2csharp converter):

```
 class InventoryJsonData
    {
        public class RootObject
        {
            public bool Success { get; set; }
            public object Error { get; set; }
            public double Price { get; set; }
            public string Username { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

Then i did the following coding:

```
ValueLoadingIndicator.IsActive = true;
var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(JsonBaseuri + IDInput.Text);
httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
```

There is only one RootObject in the JSON Data. How do i get now the Price value so i can convert it into string and display it. I dont know what i need to add as c# code. 
If you got helpful links to JSON c# tutorials and webrequest which are about this topic and can help me to move on they are appreciated as well.

Comment: you sure you want to post?

Comment: `Deserialize` your string to an instance of `RootObject`.It'll do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look and Newtonsoft Json.NET library: http://www.newtonsoft.com/json

You could also use WebClient class for you request - it's simpler to use.

Here is example code:

```
var url = JsonBaseuri + IDInput.Text;
var wc = new WebClient {Proxy = null};
var json = wc.DownloadString(url);
var responseModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<InventoryJsonData>(json);
var price = responseModel.RootObject.Price;
```

Comment: Thank you, i will use the webclient ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
HttpClient http = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
            HttpResponseMessage response = await http.GetAsync(JsonBaseuri + IDInput.Text.ToString());
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            MessageDialog x = new MessageDialog(content, "JsonData");
```

This code gets me the Json File in windows universal apps ;) then i deserialize it -> read the answers above